# CSS: Expected color, got NaNrgb

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I wanted to have a checkbox inside a Bootstrap form, which I want to turn green when it's checked. Here is my code:

```js
function test() {
  $("#check1").animate({
    "background-color": "rgb(209, 231, 221)"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><input type="checkbox" onclick="test()" id="checkbox"></span>
  <input type="text" id="check1" class="form-control" placeholder="This is a checkbox">
</div>
```

When doing this though, I get an error in the console, which states that a color was expected, but it instead recieved `NaNrgb`.
I tried this with the hex code `#d1e7dd` as well, but it failed as well.

Why is JavaScript mistaking it for a `NaN` object? Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are only starting out with jQuery, please consider just learning how to do this using a CSS animation. Otherwise, there is a good answer below about the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin for `background-color` support.

```js
function test() {
  $("#check1").animate({
    "background-color": "rgb(209, 231, 221)"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><input type="checkbox" onclick="test()" id="checkbox"></span>
  <input type="text" id="check1" class="form-control" placeholder="This is a checkbox">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even know about that plugin before, I just thought it was a strange coincidence... Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) Ya, and also its mentioned in the `.animate` jQuery docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      let checkbox = document.querySelector('#check1');
      checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
        checkbox.classList.add('/*Some class you want to add*/')
        // or 
        checkbox.style = '/*Some styling you want*/'
      });    
    </script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <span class="input-group-text"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></span>
  <input type="text" id="check1" class="form-control" placeholder="This is a checkbox">
</div>
    <input class="form-check-input danger" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
```

And please dont use onclick use eventlistern it is better
Thanks